# Windows 7 - Google Chrome messed up my FTP settings

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, ftp

I accidentally installed Google Chrome, which came with an Adobe Flash Player update. I didn't need another browser as I already have Firefox, so I uninstalled Chrome.

However, this seems to have messed up my FTP settings. Before that, I was able to connect to any FTP site via Windows Explorer. However, after I installed and removed Chrome, FTP sites would default to Internet Explorer. The option to open the FTP site in Explorer would not work.

I went to Default Programs > Set Associations, but there FTP is not listed under protocols, and there seems to be no option of adding a new protocol.

I changed the default FTP client back to Windows Explorer by editing the registry, but I now get an "Application not found" error when trying to access FTP sites.

This is a very annoying problem. I tried fully resetting Internet Explorer, but it did not help. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: This explains the registry hack http://blogs.msdn.com/b/askie/archive/2009/04/16/ftp-and-internet-explorer-what-to-do-what-to-do.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you put back the registry the way it was, (so that you don't get an error anymore when using ftp) you can change the "use internet explorer" setting here:

- Open Internet Explorer
- Press "alt" so that the "tools" menu appears
- Click tools then Internet Options
- Go to advanced tab
- Under "Browsing" you find the setting "Enable FTP folder view (outside of Internet Explorer)"

This setting should be turned on. Now you should be able to use ftp in explorer again.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that didn't work. I already have that option set.